# Skip the months from current date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT
    CAST('01 '+ RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(11), DATEADD(MONTH, -18, GETDATE()), 113), 8) AS date)
```

Output : 2018-12-01

```
SELECT 
    CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) - 1, -1) AS date)
```

Output : 2020-05-31

The query result is from dec 2018 to may 2020, but I want to skip the last 4 months.

I want output as july 2018 - dec 2019 (2018-07-01 - 2019-12-31)

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks

Comment: This date needs as per current date or it's fixed date `output as july 2018 - dec 2019 (2018-07-01 - 2019-12-31)`

Comment: Your query returns one date, not a range of dates.  I'm a little lost on what you want to do.  Are you looking to generate dates?  If so, the question should be clearer.

Comment: ok sorry ,I need range of dates only . my requirement is like i need to display last  18 months data from current date.here  my condition is only if half year is completed then only i need consider those 6 months data  from current date   ex: current month is june means 1st half of 2020 is not completed . so i need to  display the data from july 2018- dec 2019 ....if june is completed then i need to display jan 2019 - june 2020 and so on  ....help me in this how to get this ....thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check this its return last date as you expected from the current date.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,-DAY(GETDATE())+31,DATEADD(MM,-MONTH(GETDATE()), GETDATE()))) AS Date;

SELECT CAST('01 '+ RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(11),DATEADD(MONTH,-23,GETDATE()),113),8) AS DATE)
```

Ouput

```
Date
----------
2019-12-31

----------
2018-07-01
```